# Angular => hasError not displaying error with mat-form-field with mat select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got an issue with hasError on mat-form-field. Here is my code

```
   <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-design">
  <mat-label>{{
    'SETTINGS.NOTIFICATION.DAYS_SEND_LABEL' | translate
    }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="daysSend" multiple required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let currentDays of days" [value]="currentDays">
      {{'COMMON.DAYS.' + currentDays | translate}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error  *ngIf="hasError(form?.get('hourSend'), 'hoursSend', 'required')">
    {{ 'COMMON.ERRORS.DAYS_REQUIRED' | translate }}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

With that codes the message below the field isn't display, but with that codes it works

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-design">
  <mat-label>{{
    'SETTINGS.NOTIFICATION.DAYS_SEND_LABEL' | translate
    }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="daysSend" multiple required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let currentDays of days" [value]="currentDays">
      {{'COMMON.DAYS.' + currentDays | translate}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error  *ngIf="form.get('daysSend').errors && form.get('daysSend').touched">
    {{ 'COMMON.ERRORS.DAYS_REQUIRED' | translate }}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

If anyone had the same problem and fixed it, tell me your solution. Here is my hasError method who simply call hasError native method.

```
public hasError(form: AbstractControl, fc: string, validator: string) {
if (!form || !fc || !validator || !form.get(fc)) {
  return false;
}
return form.get(fc).hasError(validator);
```

}

(I specify with mat-form-field without mat-select all works fine) example =>

```
mat-form-field class="art-form-field-full-width">
        <mat-label>{{'SETTINGS.MAIN.APPEARANCE.DASHBOARD_QUOTE_LABEL' | translate}}</mat-label>
        <input matInput
               [id]="'appearance-dashboard-band-quote' + lang.value"
               [placeholder]="'SETTINGS.MAIN.APPEARANCE.DASHBOARD_QUOTE_PLACEHOLDER' | translate"
               formControlName="dashboardBandQuote"
               required/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(form?.get(lang.value), 'dashboardBandQuote', 'required')">{{
          'COMMON.ERRORS.REQUIRED' | translate
          }}</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```html
<mat-error  *ngIf="hasError(form?.get('hourSend'), 'hoursSend', 'required')">
  {{ 'COMMON.ERRORS.DAYS_REQUIRED' | translate }}
</mat-error>
```

Shouldn't you be using the following (notice the 1st parameter of `hasError`)?

```html
<mat-error  *ngIf="hasError(form, 'hoursSend', 'required')">
  {{ 'COMMON.ERRORS.DAYS_REQUIRED' | translate }}
</mat-error>
```

Comment: nope as you can see on the last method we've passed the specific field on the first param not the all form, it's works everywhere i've just have the issue with mat-form-field with mat select.

Comment: So @CharleyPons please provide a working example on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: @CharleyPons, are you sure it's working anywhere else like that? I can see at least two errors (one that I've pointed out in my answer). The other one is that you're referencing `hoursSend` to validate `daysSend`. I'm pretty confident my answer is right. But as it's possible I've got wrong what you want, I've put together this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma611761926433166?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html) to show you. It'll be easier for you to point out what the problem is.

Comment: My bad, i've made the change you've told to me, thank you very much!!!